# How does curtin, cloud-init and the ephemeral image work?

Tags: maas, cloud, cloud-init, curtin

I wanted to understand how dos cloud-init, curtin and the ephemeral image work together. I’m trying to write the role of each in the MAAS architecture.

Cloud-init has two configuration sources:

Cloud provider-supplied metadata: this stage happens before the image installation. Is this where curtin goes? it’s the configuration defined in curtin that goes in this stage?

User-supply configuration runs after the machine has Deployed. Here it’s the files that the user can run when they deploy a machine correct?

**Ephemeral image**

> Ephemeral images, use cloud-init to discover the node’s hardware (e.g., number of CPUs,RAM, disk, etc.) and send that information to the MAAS Region controller.

So ephemeral images also use cloud-init.

**Curtin**

> Curtin applies customization during operating system (OS) image installation. System parameterssuch as the type of kernel, disk partitioning, network configuration, swap memory configura-tion, among others, can be preconfigured in a preseed file that will automatically configureimages during the installation process

**What I wanted to understand is the chronology of these events, what calls what and when.**

**And what are the differences between them.**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The user triggers MaaS to deploy by telling MaaS a) which bare metal to use, a.k.a. the target bare metal b) which image and kernel you want to deploy to.
2. MaaS controls the target bare metal (usually via BMC) to power reset
3. The target bare metal netboots via PXE service provided by MaaS
4. The target bare metal boots into the ephemeral image provide by MaaS (via the previous PXE service)
5. cloud-init in the system (booted by the ephemeral image on the target bare metal) is triggered to talk to MaaS when the previous boot process completes.
6. MaaS offers the target bare metal more information and data because of the inquiry triggered by cloud-init previously.
7. cloud-init triggers curtin to write data according to the information provided in the previous step. For example, curtin knows which disk of the target bare metal should be written with the target image.
8. curtin completes to write the target image to the target disk of the target bare metal.
9. cloud-init gets the return status of curtin's writing mission, and reports the execution status and log to MaaS.
10. MaaS confirmed what cloud-init reported. If everything is ok, the target bare metal is rebooted by cloud-init, and MaaS chages the status of the target bare metal (the node) from "Deploying" to "Deployed" so MaaS will disable its PXE service for this deployed node.